# Clearfying an index in a recursion function c

Tags: c, recursion

Is it possible to set an index inside a recursion without sending a null parameter?

example:

```
void checkArry(char str[],int len){
    if(str[index] == 'P')
        printf("P");
    if(index != len)
        checkArry(str,len);

}
```

How can I set that index to start from 0 and keep adding 1 to it without it being initialized each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the index as parameter, and increment for each recursive call:

```
void checkArry(char str[],int len, int index){
    if(str[index] == 'P')
        printf("P");
    if(index != len)
        checkArry(str,len, index + 1);

}
```

and called with `checkArry(str, len, 0);`

If you do not want to add the extra index parameter, just use the `len` variable instead, and go through the array in reverse:

```
void checkArry(char str[],int len){
    if(len >= 0){
       if(str[len] == 'P')
          printf("P");
       checkArry(str, len - 1);
    }
}
```

Make sure you call the function correctly

```
checkArry(str, strlen(str) - 1);
```

We should start by the last character, hence `strlen(str) - 1`.

If for some reason you do not want to print in reverse, then you can use this version, which will print from `0 to length`:

```
void checkArry(char str[],int len){
    if(len >= 0){
       checkArry(str, len - 1);
       if(str[len] == 'P')
          printf("P");
    }
}
```